# mobileOK W3C validation/ CSS / The resource does not specify UTF-8 as character encoding

Tags: css, validation, utf-8, character-encoding

I try to validate my according to w3c [mobileOK validation tool](http://validator.w3.org/mobile)
The validation gives me a warning:
The resource does not specify UTF-8 as character encoding

WHy?:
One of the resources required to render the page (most likely a CSS style sheet) does not declare its encoding as UTF-8 in
an HTTP Content-Type header. Check that its content is properly encoded, and consider declaring its encoding at the HTTP level.

The validation tool point out my css file.

At the begining of my css, I have a correct " @charset "UTF-8";"

I have checked this site: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-charset.en.php

And it says that I can also declare the encoding of the file in the HTTP Content-Type header with something like:

Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8

I have already a comparable declaration in my html page ( < meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" / > )

But I have no clue how to use this "Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8" declaration for my css... shall I put it in css or html ? how ?

Comment: The web server needs to output that header. What's your web server?

Comment: It's a free personnal page provider (www.free.fr). do you mean it should be setup on server side? in .htaccess maybe? (I am a newbie regarding http header)

Comment: I mean the *server*, not the *provider*. Apache? IIS? nginx?

Comment: I think it's apache, but as far as I understood, not all feature can be modified

Comment: ok,I checked:  it's apache but it is not possible to modify header on my provider

Comment: If it's absolutely impossible to modify headers, even with .htaccess directives: just ignore the warning.